# Multiple count(*) in single query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need a single query to fetch the counts based on some condition(oracle).

```
select count(*) AS TOTAL_ROWS from table

select count(*) AS TOTAL_ERROR_ROWS from table where ERROR_CODE is not null

select count(*) AS TOTAL_SUCCESS_ROWS from table where ERROR_CODE is  null
```

I want to fetch all three results in 1 query. I have tried like below after googling but it is not working:

```
select
   count(*) as TotalCount,
   count(case when { where ERROR_CODE is not null} then 1 else 0 end) as QualifiedCount
from
   wli_qs_report_attribute

select count(*) as TOTAL,
    count(case when ERROR_CODE is not null then 1 else 0 end) as ExecCount,
from wli_qs_report_attribute
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT TOTAL_ROWS, TOTAL_ERROR_ROWS, TOTAL_ROWS-TOTAL_ERROR_ROWS AS TOTAL_SUCCESS_ROWS
 FROM (
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_ROWS
          , COUNT(ERROR_CODE)  AS TOTAL_ERROR_ROWS
     FROM table
 ) AS T`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` :

```
select count(*) AS TOTAL_ROWS from table

UNION

select count(*) AS TOTAL_ROWS from table where ERROR_CODE is not null

UNION

select count(*) AS TOTAL_ROWS from table where ERROR_CODE is  null
```

But it will display all three `COUNT`s in one column. To display it in three different columns try the following :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_ROWS
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN ERROR_CODE IS NOT NULL THEN * END) AS TOTAL_ERROR_ROWS
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN ERROR_CODE IS NULL THEN * END) AS TOTAL_SUCCESS_ROWS
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_ROWS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ERROR_CODE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 end) AS TOTAL_ERROR_ROWS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ERROR_CODE IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS TOTAL_SUCCESS_ROWS 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
count(case when ERROR_CODE is not null then 1 else 0 end) as ExecCount
```

Try:

```
sum(case when ERROR_CODE is not null then 1 else 0 end) as ExecCount
```